# Google Sign-In Account Popup not showing Error 12501

Tags: android, google-signin

First of all thanks in advance for any help. When trying to use Google Sign-In in my app, the pop-up to choose an account is not displayed. The activity immediately returns with error 12501. It dims the screen for a moment and that's it.

I've downloaded the samples from here https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services.git and they run fine. I can log in and log out without issue and the pop-up displays correctly. So I'm certain my SHA1 Key is correct (I'm using the debug key for now) and seeing how the samples work I'm assuming my OAuth client is properly configured.

So to summarize samples are working as intended but I can't get sign-in account pop-up to display when I start from an empty activity.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
    View.OnClickListener{

    GoogleSignInClient m_googleSignInClient;
    String m_strEmail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();
        m_googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, googleSignInOptions);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Intent intentSignIn = m_googleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(intentSignIn, 9001);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if(requestCode == 9001)
        {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try
            {
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                String m_strEmail = account.getEmail();
                Log.d("Data", "User Email: " + m_strEmail);
            }
            catch(ApiException e)
            {
                Log.w("API Exception", "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then my module gradle file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.test.chess"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Only thing I'm getting in Logcat is:

```
handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@ff6b471
signInResult:failed code=12501
```

Comment: Have you added auth client to google api console?

Comment: @Krishnasheladiya I've done everything in this tutorial https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating. So I have an activate OAuth Client and a Web client (Auto-created for Google Sign-in). 


I'm far from an expert but I was thinking it was something within the project itself because the sample projects I downloaded are working without issue, I just can't get the project I created to show the sign in dialog.

Comment: create SHA key with following command and paste it to api console .SHA key created with android studio will not work as sigin api is updated. **keytool -list -v -keystore "your jks file path here" -alias aliashere**

Comment: I'm a little confused, I got the SHA key with keytool -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore. I'm using that key with Google Sign-In samples and it's working. Why would it not work with my other project as well?

Comment: Your sha key differs for different bundle ids as well as for debug apk and release apk.

Comment: When I run google's sample sign in project with WiFi and mobile data disabled the account picker dialog still pops up. It fails to sign in (obviously because of no internet) but it still lets me choose an account. So my problem seems to be occuring before any communication with the client is performed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew this was going to be something really stupid. I've been going over this for almost a week and it turns out it's a typo... I can't imagine anyone else would have this issue but just in case here's the solution.

This is the sample code that was working:

```
GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();
        m_googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, googleSignInOptions);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
```

This is my code that wasn't working:

```
GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();
        m_googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, googleSignInOptions);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
```

I was passing in DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN whereas the samples use DEFAULT_SIGN_IN. After I corrected this everything works fine.